# Reload an online video every X seconds?

Tags: web-apps, youtube

Take for example this YouTube clip of 30 seconds: https://www.youtube.com/v/uD8JxQWMFG0?start=0&end=29&version=3

It doesn't have an auto repeat button. VLC will not repeat just the 30 seconds if you try to open the YouTube site in VLC.

In general, if you have a URL to a video, and you want it to repeat continually, what do you do?

Comment: Is something like this OK? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-replay-for-youtube/kanbnempkjnhadplbfgdaagijdbdbjeb?hl=en

Comment: or downloading the video then loop?